# Parallel Testing with bash

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have a series of tests, and I am not very good at bash. But these are the tools I have. Here goes the issue.

I need to grep for a string in a callback. I am looking for "From=". If that string is there, I basically want to go to another function I created called BAIL, which acts a a panic w/ a message.

OR I want it to just LOG that the FROM field is blank, and carry on.

If this were ruby it would be

```
( TURE && TRUE ) || TRUE
```

However I have it here in bash :

```
echo "$inbound_callback" | grep "From=$FROM" || BAIL "IB: FROM was NOT Blocked '$FROM'") || \
LOG "[$FROM -> $TO] IB: Found FROM '$FROM'"
```

Do I have to wrap the conditionals in something?

Comment: The test is really checking that the $FROM var was removed. And if it wasnt, then it would stop the test, and BAIL..

Comment: It's not clear what `$FROM` contains or how we could tell whether or not `From=` is empty without knowledge of the text around the field.  Is it on a line of its own?  Would it be followed by a newline, or some other text, or nothing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need external utilities at all.  The shell itself can examine strings and perform matching.

```
case $inbound_callback in
    *From=*) BAIL "IB: FROM was NOT Blocked '$FROM'";;
    *)       LOG "[$FROM -> $TO] IB: Found FROM '$FROM'";;
esac
```

This is simply looking for the literal strinng `From=` anywhere in the value of `inbound_callback`.  If that's not what you want, maybe rephrase your question to clarify what exactly the condition should be.

Your description of the problem sounds like you wanted to say

```
echo "$inbound_callback" | grep -q "From=" &&
BAIL "IB: FROM was NOT Blocked '$FROM'" ||
LOG "[$FROM -> $TO] IB: Found FROM '$FROM'"
```

(Notice the `&&` for the true case, and the use of `grep -q` to avoid output from a successful match.  I removed `$FROM` entirely, as you are saying you simply wanted to search for the five characters `From=`.)